# On Autocomplete Ignored and Interesting Tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, autocomplete

Why is it that the autocomplete for interesting and ignored tags still include the tags that I already added?  IMO, if that tags already exists in either of the tag clouds, if should no longer appear in the autocomplete.

Comment: Still waiting for a better answer here.

Answer (score 1):

This is also the case when adding tags to a question. Certainly it's a little quirky, but I can't imagine making it a high priority to "fix".

Answer (score 0):

They probably use the same call for all of them, but don't omit any tags. Someone else brought this same thing up, because you can add the same tag to both. It isn't a really an important bug.

Comment: I didn't tag it as a bug, but a feature-request.